Prove $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$
I want to show that $p(x)= x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.
I must show that all factorizations $p(x)=a(x)b(x)$ for $a(x),b(x)$ non-constant lead to a contradiction.
If WLOG $a(x)$ has degree $1$ and $b(x)$ has degree $3$, then some $x-\alpha$ is a factor of $p(x)$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_3$. But $p(0) \neq 0, p(1) \neq 0, p(2) \neq 0$ and so $p(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. So this factorization is impossible.
Thus, if such a factorization exists, it must be that $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ both have degree $2$. But then $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ have roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ if and only if they have roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ which cannot be the case by the previous paragraph. Does this conclude the $2+2=4$ case?

I can't follow your reasoning.  A priori, $a(x), b(x)$ might be irreducible quadratics.  How do you plan to argue against that possibility?

this question is relevant

Wait, is $\mathbb{Z}_3$ the $3$-adic integers or is it $\mathbb{F}_3$? Now 99% of the time  on MSE it is the latter, but standard useage has it $\mathbb{Z}_3$ meant the $3$-adic integers.

From your bio you are getting your PhD in math, so I trust you have studied finite fields. I also assumed  by $\mathbb{Z}_3$ you meant $\mathbb{F}_3$ the field on $3$ elements, so please correct me if I am mistaken.
Let $p(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial [of positive degree] that divides $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$, and let $\alpha$ be a root of $p(x)$. Then the equation $\alpha^5-1=0$ is satisfied [make sure you see why], or equivalently, the equation $\alpha^5=1$ holds. So, on the one hand, as $\alpha$ is not itself $1$ and satisfies $\alpha^5=1$,  any field $F$ containing $\alpha$ has to satisfy $|(F)^{\times}|$ a multiple of $5$, by Lagrange's Thm. On the other hand, the field $F = \mathbb{F}_3[x]/p(x)$ [and make sure that you see that this is indeed a field] satisfies $|(F)^{\times}| = 3^{\text{deg}(p)}-1$.
As  $|(F)^{\times}| = 3^{\text{deg}(p)}-1$ must be a multiple of $5$, it follows that deg$(p)$ has to be at least $4$. And so as $p(x)$ also divides  $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, it follows that $p(x)$ must be the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ itself, which gives the desired irreducibility.

$F$ is a field because $p(x)$ is assumed to be irreducible?  Clever; +1

@J.W.Tanner thank you! I editted and put in "irreducible" for $p(x)$ [as I should have had before] thanks to your comment

More generally, this argument would work for $x^{p-1}+\cdots+x+1$ where $3$ is a primitive root modulo odd prime $p$ (e.g., $p=7$ rather than $p=5$ as here), but not if not (e.g., $p=11$), right?

@J.W.Tanner I believe so yes

Your initial idea is a good one; none of the elements evaluate to $0$, so there are no linear factors.
Consider now multiplying out two quadratics and see whether you can get the polynomial in question. Without loss of generality, you can assume the leading coefficients are both $1$; so, can you find irreducible quadratics such that
$$(x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$$
in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$? Expanding, we find that:
$$x^4 + (a+c)x^3 + (ac+b+d)x^2 + (ad + bc)x + bd = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$$
which means that we need to find $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ such that:
$$a+c = ac+b+d = ad+bc = bd = 1$$
Can you take it from here?

$bd=1\implies b=d=-1$ or  $b=d=1$; in the former case we have $a+c=ad+bc=-(a+c)$ so $a+c=0$ contradicting $a+c=1$; in the latter case we have $a+c=ac+2$ and I got contradictions by taking $a=0, a=1,$ and $a=2$ — I don’t know if there’s a more efficient approach
